# set state of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects in state and i want to change state of that array using this.setState.

```
 state = {
   randomNumbers: [{ value: 6 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 2 }]
 };
```

i want to update these numbers with random values.
How can i update these values in a function.

```
handleUpdate = () => {
 let randomFirst = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
 let randomSecond = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
 let randomThird = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
 //i have to set state here and assign these three random numbers values to state values one by one.
 this.setState(?);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleUpdate = () => {
 this.setState({
   RandomNumbers: [
     { value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1},
     { value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1},
     { value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1},
   ],
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as follows, but why:

- are you using capital letters for your variables, properties?
- do you use the object with `value` property, can't it just use number itself?

```
        this.setState(() => ({
          RandomNumbers: [
            { value: RandomFirst },
            { value: RandomSecond },
            { value: RandomThird },
          ],
        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()` to avoid repeating yourself.

```
handleUpdate = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    RandomNumbers: prevState.RandomNumbers.map(x => ({
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    }))
  }));
};
```

Comment: very nice approach but this is setting same random number to all values.

Comment: @Zohaib Sorry, `fill()` isn't a good approach, updated. In this way, you can keep the same length, as well as keep the code dry.